# Beamer: Using sans serif numbers in math mode together with LuaLaTeX and the fontspec package

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode, luatex

This is a follow up on my last [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155901/first-steps-with-lualatex-and-ttf-fonts). I want to produce a `beamer` presentation using the font `Helvetica Neue`. I am using this MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[
  BoldFont=HelveticaNeueLTCom-Md,
  ItalicFont=HelveticaNeueLTCom-LtIt, 
  SmallCapsFont=TeXGyre Heros,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]{HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test 1 2 3}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{italic}
\item \textbf{bold}
\item normal
\item numbers: 1, 2, 3 and 4
\item math
\begin{align}
a^2 + b^2 &= c^\text{2} \text{ (used \texttt{\textbackslash text} to produce sans serif 2 for $c$)}\\
\alpha^2 + \beta^2 &= \gamma^2
\end{align}
\item \textsc{SmallCaps}
\item Dash -- Dash
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

With the following result:

[image]

1. How do I change the font with is used for numbers in math mode? I can use `\text` all the time but this is not a clever solution.
2. Is the code ok that way? I didn't use the `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` beamer command because I think this is not useful in my case.
3. The dash `--` does not work. How can that be fixed?
4. The SmallCaps font look too thick in combination with the thin main font. Has anybody a suggestion for a better SmallCaps replacement? I looked here http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/ and it also says that

> TeX Gyre Heros can be used as a replacement for a popular font Helvetica

---

**Update**

Following Mico's advice leads to missing greek letters such like `\alpha` and `\beta`. I removed the `greek` and `Greek` option but the letters are still missing:

```
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin,num}]{HelveticaNeueLTCom-Th}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,num}]{HelveticaNeueLTCom-ThIt}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{latin,Latin,num}]{HelveticaNeueLTCom-Roman}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{latin,Latin,num}]{HelveticaNeueLTCom-It}
```

[image]

The warnings in the log file look like:

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (+ssty) not available for font
* 'HelveticaNeueLTCom-ThIt' with script 'Math' and language 'Default'.
*************************************************
luaotfload: font no 25 (HelveticaNeueLTCom-ThIt) does not define feature ssty fo
r script latn with language dflt
luaotfload: no font with id 25
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Style=MathScriptScript' (+ssty) not available for font
* 'HelveticaNeueLTCom-ThIt' with script 'Math' and language 'Default'.
*************************************************
```

Using `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` or not does not have an effect on the output (as far as I can see).

Comment: Regarding your new question: The reason why the small-caps glyphs of `TexGyre Heros` look to thick next to the glyphs of `HelveticaNeueLTCom-Th` is because the latter is (as its name indicates) designed to be, well, "thin". See if you can get a better match if you choose either `HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt` or `HelveticaNeueLTCom-Roman` as the main (sans-serif) font.

Comment: HelveticaNeueLTCom has _no math_!

Comment: Hello Herbert. Thereofre I thought that using \setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin,num}]{HelveticaNeueLTCom-Th} would help.

Comment: Ahhhh....I didn't see the mathup part...maybe I should use something different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setsansfont[
  BoldFont=HelveticaNeueLTCom-Md,
  ItalicFont=HelveticaNeueLTCom-LtIt, 
  SmallCapsFont=TeXGyre Heros,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]{HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt}
\setmathfont{HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{greek}]{TeXGyre Heros Italic}
```

Comment: I will try it later (I am not at my PC). Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Taking your questions in reverse order:

- To enable the automatic substitution of `--` and `---` with endash and emdash symbols, be sure to load the font in question with the option `Ligatures=TeX`, i.e.,

  ```
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX,
    Extension=.ttf,
    BoldFont=HelveticaNeueLTCom-Md,
    ItalicFont=HelveticaNeueLTCom-LtIt, 
    SmallCapsFont=TeXGyre Heros,
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
   ]{HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt}
  ```

  I can't show the output that would result from this modification because I don't have these fonts on my system. Setting the option `Ligatures=TeX` option will also replace `` with typographically correct opening double-quote marks.
- You've so far specified a text (sans serif) font but no math font; thus, the math parts show up in Computer/Latin Modern. You should load the `unicode-math` package (which, in turn, loads the `fontspec` package) and issue a few directives that tell LuaLaTeX to use, as much as possible, characters from the text font families. (As far as I'm aware, there are no opentype *sans-serif* math font available.)

  ```
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setsansfont{TeXGyre Heros}
  \setmathfont[range=\mathup/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}]{TeXGyre Heros}
  \setmathfont[range=\mathit/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}]{TeXGyre Heros Italic}
  \setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}]{TeXGyre Heros Bold}
  \setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{greek,Greek,latin,Latin,num}]{TeXGyre Heros Bold Italic}
  ```

  Here, I've used various weights and shapes of the TeXGyre Heros fonts. Assuming that the HelveticaNeue fonts have Greek letters, you may be able to replace `TeXGyre Heros` with `HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt`, etc.

  If you have a lot of math in your beamer doc, you you consider seriously using one of `professionalfonts` options, say, the `arev` class.
- The preceding discussion should also enable the use of sans-serif numbers in math mode.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. It doesn't work with my font. Maybe the fonts are not good/complete enough.