# What is the best way to have very good control over fonts?

Tags: fonts

Embarrassing question, but I usually focus completely on layout and don't bother to mess with the font, except when I'm really feeling experimental and use libertine...

Anyway, what is the best way to have full control over a modern font family, like Helvetica neue, and be able to shift between, say, ultrialightweight and normal, at any size?

Is there any way to say `\font{helvetica}{ultralight}{48pt}` or something?

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate or bad question, but fonts in LaTeX are just something I've never understood.

Should I be looking into learning to use XeTeX or something, instead?

Comment: See also the posting [First steps with LuaLaTeX and ttf fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155901/5001). The answers to that posting deal specifically with how to go about shifting between font weights of a "font superfamily" -- such as Helvetica (Neue) -- which features lots of font weights, not just "regular" and "bold".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which is the best way, but with XeLaTeX or LuaLateX the `fontspec` package allows you to simply do that.

For example, if your document has `12pt` using `Scale=4` as in

```
\fontspec{Helvetica Light}[Scale=4]
```

should give you what you want.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Helvetica}

\begin{document}

This is a very {\fontspec{Helvetica Light}[Scale=4] big} word

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

P.S. If you have an old version of `fontspec` the syntax

```
\fontspec{Helvetica Light}[Scale=4]
```

might not work. In this case use the old syntax

```
\fontspec[Scale=4]{Helvetica Light}
```

Comment: Now the syntax is `\fontspec{Helvetica}[Scale=4]`.

Comment: @Manuel - Both syntactic forms are OK.

Comment: @Mico They both work *now*, but in the future the one I used is the one planned, or am I wrong?

Comment: @manuel - I can offer no special insights into the plans of the authors/maintainers of the `fontspec` package. All I know is that should the older syntactical form no longer be valid at some point in the future, lots and lots and lots of documents will no longer compile correctly. As such, I certainly hope that both syntactical forms will remain valid.

Comment: Yes @Manuel changed to the new syntax

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks! Are there any reasons not to use XeLaTeX, or will everything still work like I expect it it to?

Comment: @Ryan I don't think you'll have any problems switching to XeLaTeX, but only benefits (for example you can use any installed font in your document)... Anyway see this great answer of Joseph Wright for more info about the differences: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222300/27635

Comment: Thanks, I get the feeling this is going to be one of those "why didn't I ever do this before..." Kinds of things.

Comment: @Ryan I do agree with you!

Comment: @Manuel I'm not sure why, but only the older syntax `\fontspec[Scale=4]{Helvetica Light}` works for me. Maybe include both in your answer, @karlkoeller?

Comment: @Ryan You need to update your packages.

Comment: @Ryan Done. Anyway consider updating your TeX distribution ;-)

Comment: @Ryan If you want complete *micro-typographical* control (with `microtype`), pdfTeX remains the best option, although there is now substantial support for LuaTeX. As I understand it, support for XeTeX is more limited (but by no means non-existent). However, for fonts which lack traditional support packages, XeTeX or LuaTeX are far and away the easiest options.